# PHP - Receiving XML requests

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, http-request

I am sending packets of data to a desktop application using PHP Curl, this works using a specific IP address and port to request and post information.

What I need to do now is the opposite and send information from a desktop application and process them on the web as soon as I receive them.

The information will be sent in XML format.

I've been looking into how I can achieve this and so far I have come across NuSOAP and PHP. I am just wondering if this is the way forward to achieve what it is I need to do.

As much information would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a one-liner in php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('php://input');
```

This assumes that

- php is running behind a web server (typically, Apache)
- the request is a standard HTTP POST request
- xml data is sent raw in a request body